# When I renamed a class I am getting a deserialization error. How to fix it?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, serialization

I renamed the class `classBattle` to `Game` and not I get "Unable to load type battle.classBattle+udtCartesian required for deserialization."

This is the line of code `MapSize = (Game.udtCartesian)formatter.Deserialize(fs);`

How do I fix this? Does this mean I cannot rename classes?

Comment: For completeness, you *might* be able to fix this with a "serialization surrogate", but that is messy and hard work. Better to start with a contract-based serializer in the first place. Also, you can *move* types (between assemblies) as long as you use `[TypeForwardedTo]` - but not so easy to rename.

Comment: I need to learn how to serialize with XmlSerialize first. I am trying to modify http://www.codeproject.com/KB/game/BattleField.aspx to learn strategy game programming. The map editor uses the BinaryFormatter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`BinaryFormatter` is brittle, and is not designed to be friendly [if you have changes to the types involved](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/03/obfuscation-serialization-and.html). If you want that type of behaviour, you need a contract-based serializer such as `XmlSerializer`, `DataContractSerializer` or protobuf-net. Anything except `BinaryFormatter`.

Comment: I was going to post an answer recommending http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net but I will defer to Marc (who wrote it!).

Answer (score 5):

You could also use a `SerializationBinder` to define which type will be loaded in the case that another type is being deserialized:

```
public sealed class Version1ToVersion2DeserializationBinder : SerializationBinder
{
    public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
        Type typeToDeserialize = null;

        if (typeName == "OldClassName")
            typeName = "NewClassName";

        typeToDeserialize = Type.GetType(String.Format("{0}, {1}",
                                            typeName, assemblyName));

        return typeToDeserialize;
    }
}
```

To deserialize, you just have to set the `Binder` property of the `BinaryFormatter`:

```
formatter.Binder = new Version1ToVersion2DeserializationBinder();
NewClassName obj = (NewClassName)formatter.Deserialize(fs);
```

Answer (score 1):

When serializing if not using contracts, the name of the class is part of it, so it stands to reason that to deserialize the class name needs to be the same.

You can change the class name, serialize again and deserialize without a problem.

What will not work is serializing with one name and attempting to deserialize back to a different name.

Other then that, use contracts and a formatter that uses them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not concerned about saved data, just delete the file, the new one will be saved using new name.